# RubyMine test runner tab not showing the tree view while running tests

Tags: rubymine, test-runner

I'm using RubyMine 2016.1.2 and whenever I run a test the tree view doesn't show up in the left hand test toolbar. According to this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/test-runner-tab.html 
items 2,3, and 6 are missing but should be there. I have tried editing the views and settings to see if there was something there that would enable but haven't had any luck. Does anyone know how to get this view to show?

Answer (score 0):

In the edit configurations, "runner options" I had '--format pretty'
Once that was removed it showed the correct view.

Answer (score 0):

In Rubymine Go to > Configuration> Runner Options > Then remove --format pretty > Apply > Ok > Click on Run Button. Then the Test Runner will be displayed.

[image]